# Set button attribute inside Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, button, gridview

I have a button inside a Gridview. What I want to do is when the button is clicked simply change the button color.
However, after publishing the paged and clicking the button nothing happens.
Am I missing a step.

Here is my .aspx code

```
<asp:GridView   id="gvStatus" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="White" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" GridLines="Both" Pager="10" OnRowDataBound="setcolor" OnRowCommand="setsingle" >
        <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="1"  Visible="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass= "hdrBase" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridBase">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button id="btnDOne" Width="35px"  Height ="25px" runat="server" Text='<%#(Eval("dateone", "{0:ddd}"))%>' CommandName="GetData" CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" ></asp:Button>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>        
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And here is the c#

```
        protected void setsingle(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {   
        if (e.CommandName == "GetData")
            { 
                //Get row index
                int rowindex  = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                ////Get Row
                GridViewRow gvr = gvStatus.Rows[rowindex];
                //Find the button
                Button DayButton = gvr.FindControl("btnDOne") as Button;    
                //Set the color of the button
                DayButton.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
            }
```

To test if the code was working added a linkbutton to the Gridview and gave it the same CommandName:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="1"  Visible="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass= "hdrBase" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridBase">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button id="btnDOne" Width="35px"  Height ="25px" runat="server" Text='<%#(Eval("dateone", "{0:ddd}"))%>' CommandName="GetData" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ></asp:Button>
                    <asp:LinkButton id="lbd1" runat="server"  Text="clickme " CommandName="GetData" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

So, the linkbutton executes the behind code no problem. But the commandbutton does not execute anything. In the last code snippet you will notice I compared the two and basically made the commandbutton match the linkbutton as far as the `CommandArgument` goes.

I have verified the behind code works, as well as the CommandName assignment is correct. 
Is there a different way to do this for a commandbutton?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in `setsingle`?

Comment: button clicks trigger `PostBacks` there are actually lots of examples on how to add attributes to asp.net controls do a google search to see

Comment: @Tim I did set a breakpoint and the code is fine, I updated my findings  and i believe i am missing something on e command button just not sure what.

Comment: @Tommy: you've said you've set a breakpoint and the code is fine. That would mean there is no issue anymore. I suggested to use a breakpoint in codebehind to see if a postback is triggered at all from the button(breakpoint in `Page_Load`) and if the `RowCommand`-event handler is executed at all(breakpoint in `setsingle`). You can also check in `setsingle`(if executed) what values you get there. Another option is to handle the button's `Click`-event. That's even simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning the command buttons and going with the link buttons then setting the back-color of the Grid cell as needed.